# Visual Studio Debug SQL Server Connection String - "SSL Provider, error 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I recently wiped my laptop and reinstalled everything, including Visual Studio. Since doing so, my connection string for an intranet web app (connecting to a local SQL Server DB) no longer works in debug...

```
<add name="Company Database" connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance;Initial Catalog=&quot;DBName&quot;;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User;Password=Pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It works fine when deployed to a server, but when I try to run the app in debug I get the error "SSL Provider, error 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted". The posts I've found matching this error typically suggest to use (with caution for an external facing app) encrypt=false or TrustServerCertificate=true. When I try these, the text is underlined in green and tooltip displays "the encrypt attribute is not allowed". Have tried updating "System.Data.SQLClient" to "Microsoft.Data.SQLClient" but this doesn't appear to make any difference.
Can anyone assist please?
Thanks

Comment: Switched to <sql-server> tag. (SQL is a _language_, and not related to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is likely because the SSL certificate for your SQL Server is not trusted by your machine or Visual Studio.
Here are several potential solutions:

Solution 1: Considering "TrustServerCertificate=true" did not solve
the problem, you may want to try adding "encrypt=false" to your
connection string. This tells SQL Server to not encrypt the
communication, which can circumnavigate SSL misconfigurations.

Solution 2:
It's possible that the SQL Server that you're trying to connect to is using a self-signed SSL certificate. If it's acceptable in the context of your project, consider having the SQL Server use a certificate from a well-known, trustworthy certificate authority.

Solution 3:
Consider importing the SQL Server's SSL certificate into your machine's trusted root certificate store. This should make your machine trust the SSL certificate.

Solution 4:
Unchecked Encrypt connection under tab Connection Properties
[image]

Please remember to exercise caution and ensure that any changes to your security settings are consistent with your security requirements.

Comment: As per the original post, Visual Studio will not accept the syntax for "TrustServerCertificate" or "Encrypted". I get the error "the encrypt attribute is not allowed"

Comment: These are unrelated, you probably just want `TrustServerCertificate=true`. Encrypt = false means don't use SSL which is a bad idea

Comment: I've already tried to use this but I can't get it to accept the syntax. Error - "The 'TrustServerCertificate' attribute is not allowed"

Comment: Have a try solution 4:
Unchecked Encrypt connection under tab Connection Properties of SSMS